# Date format in AngularJS and Symfony

Tags: angularjs, date, symfony

I'm trying to display a date in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" in AngularJS. I'm retrieving data from database with symfony2.

When I inspect my scope in the browser it looks like I have a valid date object:

```
CreationDate : Object { date="2014-05-15 00:00:00", timezone_type=3, timezone="Europe/Paris"}
```

Here is what i have tried:

```
{{res.creationDate  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

which prints this:

```
{"date":"2014-08-12 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Paris"}
```

and quite logically:

```
{{res.creationDate.date }} --> 2014-05-15 00:00:00`
```

I'd like to have "15-05-2014"

---- EDIT

My controller:

```
public function ViewAction()
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:MyEntity');


        $list = $repository->getArray();
        $list = json_encode($list);

        return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle:Search:search.html.twig', array('list' => $list) );
    }
```

My custom getArray function in repo:

```
public function getArray()
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    return $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

My template looks something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" ng-init= "result= {{list}}">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <div ng-repeat="res in result | filter:searchText | filter:nom | filter :prenom | limitTo:50 " >

                    <li class="list-group-item">Date {% verbatim %} {{res.creationDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }} {% endverbatim %}</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

creationDate is a "date" format, in a SQL Database. In phpmyadmin it  prints 'dd-mm-yyy'

Comment: Doesn't it look like one ? Not a criticism , real question...

Comment: didn't manage to use jsfiddle but edit my comment, hope its somehow understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can alter the date object from `date="2014-05-15 00:00:00"` to `date="2014-05-15T00:00:00"` it should work.

Working example at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sorendam/p6qn2so3/2/)

You might also want to take a look on this post about [JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format)

Comment: Well that's a great info thanks i think this is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

If you try to format the date directly?

```
{{res.creationDate.date  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

Comment: didn't want to be redundant.. but still prints 2014-05-15 00:00:00.  as res.creationDate.date isn't an object ( well that's my guess :p )

Comment: Ok. Can you create an object with your date?
Like 
    new Date(res.creationDate.data);
And then display this object?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wondering..
Here is a trick i came up with for my problem 
view

```
{{ mySplit(res.symfonyDateObject.date, 0) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
```

controller

```
app.controller('SearchController', function($scope)
{

    $scope.mySplit = function(string, nb) {
        $scope.array = string.split(' ');
        return $scope.array[nb];

    }
});
```

tldr i split the string in half, remove the hh/mm/ss and then angular format works

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `Date` object to convert your timestamp(2014-05-15 00:00:00) into a time string(1400092200000) and apply angular filter

Working example at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6qn2so3/4/)